# a question about fixed-point-free automorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a finite group with a fixed-point-free automorphism a of order 3. Prove that [x,y,y]=1 for all x,y in G.

Comment: It was proved by Burnside that a group with a fixed-point-free automorphism of order $3$ is nilpotent of class at most $2$, which immediately implies this result. I will help you prove it if you say what you have tried, and what things you know about groups with a ficed-point-free automorphism of order $3$.

Comment: for any x in G,I know x can commute with a^{-1}xa, It's a exerciser from Robinson's book A course in the theory of groups.Page308.

Comment: actually,I have another question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706526/the-nilpotency-class-of-frobenius-kernal

Comment: As I said in my comment on your other question, I do not understand what you are asking. Try and ask a more precise question.

Answer (score 3):

I will summarize the proof from the book "Theory of Groups of Finite Order" by W. Burnside. It would not be very easy to think of this if you had not seen it before!

With your notation, conjugation by $a$ is inducing a fixed-point-free automorphism of order $3$ of $G$. You know that $x$ commutes with $a^{-1}xa$ and similarly with $axa^{-1}$.

If you conjugate $(axa^{-1})x(a^{-1}xa)$ by $a$ then you get $x(a^{-1}xa)(axa^{-1})$, which is the same element, so $(axa^{-1})x(a^{-1}xa) = 1$, and hence $x \in \langle a^{-1}xa,axa^{-1} \rangle$.

Since $a$ acts fixed-point-freely, the $|G|$ elements $g^{-1}ag$ for $g \in G$ are all distinct, and they are all of the form $g'a$ for some $g' \in G$, so we have $\{ g^{-1} a g : g \in G \} = \{ga : g \in G \}$.

You are trying to prove that $[[x,y],y]=1$ for all $x,y \in G$, which is equivalent to proving that $y$ commutes with $x^{-1}yx$.

By the above, we have $xa = g^{-1}ag$ for some $g \in G$. Now $g^{-1}ag$ also has order $3$ and acts fixed-point-freely on $G$, so $y$ commutes with $(g^{-1}a^{-1}g)y(g^{-1}ag) = a^{-1}x^{-1}yxa$. Similarly, $y$ commutes with $ax^{-1}yxa^{-1}$. But we saw above that $x^{-1}yx \in \langle a^{-1}x^{-1}yxa,ax^{-1}yxa^{-1} \rangle$, so $y$ commutes with $ x^{-1}yx$, and we are done.

Comment: Nice answer as usual! Thank you very much Prof. Holt!

Comment: Thanks, it's a good answer for me.

Comment: @Derek Sorry I even can't see why [x, a]=1, could you elaborate the detail please. Also, 'a' is a automorphism function but not an element in G isn't it? So does all the 'a' in your post above means a(x) for abbreviation but not an element in G?

Comment: I didn't say $[x,a]=1$. I am working in a semidirect product $G \rtimes \langle a \rangle$ with $a$ of order $3$, where the action of conjugation by $a$ on $G$ induces a fixed point free automorphism of $G$. So $a$ is a group element, not an automorphism.