# the nilpotency class of Frobenius kernel

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

As we know, if G has a fixed-point-free automorphism of order p, then G is nilpotent, can we know something about the nilpotency class of Frobenius kernel ?

Comment: Could you add come further detail? The term Frobenius kernel has two different meanings, and it is only nilpotent in one of them (which can be distinguished by the tags, but it would still be nice to have the question not need this).

Comment: Well I know that the Frobenius kernel of the dihedral group of order $6$ is nilpotent of class $1$. Why don't you try and ask a more sensible question. (For example: "is it true that for every $n>0$ there exists a Frobenius group whose kernel is nilpotent of class $n$?" would be a good question.)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $K$ is a finite group with a fixed-point-free automorphism of prime order. Then Thompson (1959) showed $K$ is nilpotent.

Suppose $K$ is a finite solvable (or locally nilpotent) group with a fixed-point-free automorphism of prime order $p$. Then Higman (1957) showed $K$ is nilpotent with nilpotency class bounded above by a function, $k(p)$, of $p$.

A textbook presentation of Higman's results is in Huppert–Blackburn VIII.10, see especially VIII.10.15. Larry Wilson's 2007 article is a fairly easy read with a good survey of the techniques.

The values of $k(p)$ were calculated:

- $k(2)=1$ Burnside (1910, page 90; also classical),
- $k(3)=2$ Burnside (1910, page 90-91) and Neumann (1956) for an infinite case,
- $k(5)=6$ Higman (1957),
- $k(7)=12$ Scimemi (1970s, unpublished computer calculation), Hughs (1985, computer free)
- $30 \leq k(11) \leq 118$ Favaretto (1998, computer)

And general bounds were established:

- $\frac{p^2-1}{4} \leq k(p) \leq \frac{(p-1)^{\left(2^{(p-1)}-1\right)}-1}{p-2}$ Higman (1957).
- $k(p) \leq (p-1)^{\left(2^{(p-1)}-2\right)}$  Meixner (1980)
- $\frac{(p-2)^{\left(2^{(p-1)}-1\right)}-1}{p-3}$ Shumyatsky–Tamarozzi–Wilson (2005)
- $\frac{(p-3)^{\left(2^{(p-5)} + \lfloor \log_2((p-3)/2)\rfloor \right)}-1}{p-4}
  + (p-2)^{\left(2^{((p-5)/2)}+\lfloor\log_2((p-1)/2)\rfloor\right)}$
  Wilson (2007)

But all general bounds are very far from the conjectured $\frac{p^2-1}{4}$ which is sharp for odd $p \leq 7$. Much better bounds are available if the derived length can be shown to be reasonable (the conjecture is the derived length is logarithmic in $p$; the general bounds have only been able to use exponential bounds).

### Bibliography

- Burnside, W. Theory of Groups, 2ed. (1910) -- uses a 1902 paper of Burnside for $k(3)$.
- Neumann, B. H.
  [“Groups with automorphisms that leave only the neutral element fixed.”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01900516)
  Arch. Math. (Basel) 7 (1956), 1–5.
  MR[74413](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=74413)
- Higman, Graham.
  [“Groups and rings having automorphisms without non-trivial fixed elements.”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-32.3.321)
  J. London Math. Soc. 32 (1957), 321–334. 
  MR[89204](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=89204)
- Thompson, John.
  [“Finite groups with fixed-point-free automorphisms of prime order.”](http://www.jstor.org/stable/90107)
  Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 45 (1959) 578–581.
  MR[104731](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=104731)
- Kreknin, V. A.; Kostrikin, A. I.
  “Lie algebras with regular automorphisms.”
  Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 149 (1963) 249–251.
  MR[146230](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=146230)
- [Scimemi, Benedetto.](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg1=INDI&s1=196115&extend=1) (unpublished.)
- Meixner, Thomas.
  [“Metabelsche Gruppen mit einem fixpunktfreien Automorphismus von Primzahlordnung.”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01235373)
  Arch. Math. (Basel) 35 (1980), no. 6, 497–500 (1981).
  MR[604247](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=604247)
- Hughes, Ian.
  “Groups with fixed-point-free automorphisms.”
  C. R. Math. Rep. Acad. Sci. Canada 7 (1985), no. 1, 61–66. 
  MR[777766](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=777766)
- Favaretto, M. “Contributi alla soluzione di una congettura relativa alle algebre di Lie nilpotenti,” Ph.D. Thesis, Università Ca’ Foscari Venezia, 1998.
- Shumyatsky, Pavel; Tamarozzi, Antonio; Wilson, Lawrence.
  [“$\mathbb{Z}_n$-graded Lie rings.”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2004.09.004)
  J. Algebra 283 (2005), no. 1, 149–160.
  MR[2102076](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2102076)
- Wilson, Lawrence.
  [“The nilpotency class of groups with fixed point free automorphisms of prime order.”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511721205.032)
  Groups St. Andrews 2005. Vol. 2, 685–701, 
  London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 340, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 2007.
  MR[2331626](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2331626)

Comment: Jack, great answer, thanks for putting this all together!

Answer (score 3):

There is a theorem of Ito: let $q$ be a prime power, $d$ a positive integer, and $p$ a prime divisor of $q−1$ with $d \leq p$. Fix some field $F$ of order $q$ and some element $\alpha$ of this field of order $p$. The Frobenius complement $H$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by the diagonal matrix whose $(i,i)$th entry is $\alpha^i$. The Frobenius kernel $K$ is he Sylow $q$-subgroup of $GL(d,q)$ consisting of upper triangular matrices with $1$'s on the diagonal. The kernel $K$ has nilpotency class $d−1$, and the semidirect product $KH$ is a Frobenius group.

Comment: I am glad that you under the question! Another possible interpretation is whether there exists a bound on the nilpotency class of the kernel as a function of $p$, and I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: Ah, that is something different, yes.

Comment: If $H$ is cyclic of prime order, then yes (H-B VII.10.15 or so; it points to Burnside for the p=3 version.)

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Excellent! It's actually VIII.10.15, and the class $c$ of $G$ is at most $\xi(2^{p-1}-1)$, where $\xi(n) = 1 + (p-1) + \cdots + (p-1)^{n-1}$. That gives $357913941$ for $p=5$ and $2111342888765775923538742898227062886996548727603$ for $p=7$. Oh well!!

Comment: I added more up to date bounds (for p=5 and 7 they are sharp, for p=11 they are pretty good, for larger p they are still insane).

Comment: @NickyHekster: where did you find Ito's construction? Higman's construction is all generators and relations (yuck). Your example is very clear.

Comment: The example with the upper triangular matrices is in Huppert, "Endliche Gruppen I", in the section on fixed-point-free automorphisms.

Comment: Yes that is correct, the example comes from Endliche Gruppen I. Also Isaacs' Finite Group Theory gives a similar example in the Chapter 6, Frobenius Actions (in my copy on p. 180).