# a question about fixed-point-free automorphism group 2

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In this paper, [Rowley (1995)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1995.1148), there is a theorem:

> Let $A$ and $G$ be finite groups. Suppose that $A$ acts fixed-point-freely on $G$ and that either $A$ is cyclic or $(|G|,|A|)=1$. Then $G$ is soluble.

I have two questions

1. Is there a proof without recourse to the simple group classification for this theorem ?
2. $G$ is soluble, can the derived length of $G$ be bounded?

I can't communicate with the author, I will be very glad if someone can reply.

- Rowley, Peter.
  [“Finite groups admitting a fixed-point-free automorphism group.”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1995.1148)
  J. Algebra 174 (1995), no. 2, 724–727.
  MR[1334233](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1334233)

Comment: People are more likely to reply if you acknowledge help received by accepting answers. You got detailed replies to your earlier questions http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706526 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706200. Why can't you communicate with the author?

Comment: I can't communicate with the author because I have no his email address.

Comment: That is on his home page at the University of Manchester.

Comment: Thank you, I have sent an email to the author.

Comment: This is a nice paper! The use of CFSG is very clean and clear.