# $G$ be a finite group and $f \in Aut (G)$ such that $f^3$ is identity and $f$ has unique fixed point , then any $p$-Sylow subgroup is normal?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite group and $f \in Aut (G)$ such that $f^3$ is identity and $f(x)=x \implies x=e$ ; then is it true that for every prime $p$ dividing $|G|$ , there is exactly one $p$-Sylow subgroup i.e. that $p$-Sylow subgroup is normal in $G$ ?

Comment: It may be useful to say the background of the problem so that the one who wants to answer may have better idea what properties they can use

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik : It is a problem on sylow theory , one can use cauchy and sylow thorems , class equation , group action .. though I am not getting anywhere ..

Comment: It is true. It was proved by Burnside that such groups are nilpotent of class at most $2$. There is some information here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706200 although that is a slightly different question.

Comment: @DerekHolt : I also saw that this is an exercise of Herstein's topics in algebra . So shouldn't it have some elementary solution ?

Comment: Some of the problems in Herstein's book are notoriously difficult. In any case, the solution by Burnside is elementary. Elementary does not imply easy.