# The composition of a fixedpoint-free automorphisms with conjugation is again fixedpoint-free

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Let $(G,*)$ be a finite group and $\psi \in \text{Aut}(G)$ a fixedpoint-free automorphism, that is, if $\psi(x) = x$, then $x = 1$.

In a proof I am reading there is the following incidental remark:
If $g \in G$, then the map $x \mapsto g * \psi(x) * g^{-1}$ is "clearly" again a fixedpoint-free automorphism.

**Question**: *Why* ist this automorphism fixedpoint-free? It is not obvious for me.

Thank you for your thoughts!

EDIT:
It follows the original proof mentioned above: the author uses postfix notation for maps, i.e., $x\psi$ for $\psi(x)$. All rules are formed accordingly.

[image]

EDIT2: Is the proof of the following really "obvious"?
[image]

Comment: Let $\psi^g$ be the map $\psi^g(x)=g\psi(x)g^{-1}$.
Then

$$\psi^g(x)=x\iff \psi(x)=g^{-1}xg$$

We know that $\psi$ cannot be the conjugation by $g$, for otherwise $g$ and its powers would be fixed points of $\psi$.
This means that $\psi(x)=g^{-1}xg$ must fail for *some* $x\neq e$.
However, in principle I don't know why $\psi(x)=g^{-1}xg$ should fail for *all* $x\neq e$.
Are there other relevant assumptions in the proof?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: Thank you for your thoughts! I have added the proof for inspection.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I gave a summary of the original proof by Burnside  of this result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706200)

Comment: @Derek Holt: Thank you! Such alternatives are _always_ very welcome.

Comment: What is the mentioned Lemma? I suppose by $x^{\phi}$ he means $\phi(x)$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: Correct $x^\phi = \phi(x)$. The notation is not mine. I will add a screnshot of Lemma 5.2: if you look at it closely, the same question will arise again that I asked.

Comment: Is $G$ assumed to be abelian? This is quite weird.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: No, I do not see any constraints stating that $G$ is abelian. If you run out of ideas, then we have something in common :-) Anyway, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, consider [this reference](http://www.algebra.uni-linz.ac.at/~stein/papers/fpfaut.pdf), in particular page $17$ of the document $(26$ of the pdf$)$, for the proof of Lemma $5.2$.
In the reference, it's on letter $(d)$ of Lemma $3.2$.

Now, the reference also answers the main question.
Indeed, let $x$ be a fixed point of $\psi_g$. Then $x=$ $g\,\psi(x)\,g^{-1}$, that is $x$ and $\psi(x)$ are conjugate, by $g$.
As shown in letter $(c)$ of Lemma $3.2$ in our reference, this implies $x=1_G$.
In other words, the only fixed point of $\psi_g$ is the identity, and hence $\psi_g$ is fixed-point-free.

---

As a side note, your Lemma $5.2$ implies, by direct computation, that $\psi_g$ also satisfies $\psi_g^3=\text{Id}$.

Comment: This is just great! Thank you again for your patience and the  perfect reference.